# I want to fake a specific IP address when hitting a site

Tags: networking

I work for a global company and we have users who are saying they can't get to our site from a specific country.  That country has users logging into our machine according to our backend.  So we got one of the users who can't see the site to send us their IP address.  I want to hit our site with their specific IP address to see if somehow there is a difference.  How would I go about setting up my computer to be his IP address in a way that outside our network I still show that specific IP address?

Comment: use teamviewer, vnc, ssh, proxy, vpn, rdesktop...

Comment: Spoofing won't solve this.  You need traceroute's from users.

Comment: To expand on Tyson's answer, the problem likely has to do with the path from the source network to your network. Faking the IP address won't suddenly make your packet originate in the problem location or follow the problem path.

Comment: In addition, spoofing an IP address would cause more problems as the Internet won't know how to return your packets to you.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone.  For now we've added more error tracking to our code to see if we can determine anything else.  I am thinking right now that the ISP may be the problem.  One reason may be because the Isle of Man is right between Ireland and the UK so maybe they have an Irish ISP which could possibly show the user as originating from there and if so they would encounter the problem they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VPN inside that country may not be an option either for you but it may be an option for them to use a VPN outside their country.

Another option is use a host like GOogle to translate the site or Archive.org to link it.

a cloud browser like Puffin on iOS is like a proxy browser in the USA might work for them.

Teamviewer with a volunteer remote user might work but then expose your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some user in that country who faces this problem to setup a remote desktop connection (like TeamViewer etc.) and then access their computer.

Another method would be to try using a proxy server or VPN from that country and see if you encounter the problem. This, however, may not work as some notorious ISP may be the blocker.